# I'm getting an Exception Error when using %S

Tags: c

```
int main()
 {
 int Age;
 char Name;

 //Age

 printf("Type your age: ");
 scanf_s("%d", &Age);
 printf("Your age is %d\n", Age);

 //Name

 printf("Type your Name: ");
 scanf_s("%s", &Name);
 printf("Your name is %s", Name);

 return 0; }
```

It's the 'Name' section which is throwing out an error. I can't figure out why.

UPDATE: I'm coding in Visual Studio. Therefore, "scanf_s" is essentially required.

The error is "Exception thrown at 0x5B49D4EC (ucrtbased.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x001A0000. occurred"

Comment: Read the documentation of `scanf_s`

Comment: You char Name is also just one character, you will need to cast Name as arrays of characters. e.g. char Name[]

Comment: If this was solved with help of one of the answers, please mark the answer as 'Accepted'

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add *SOLVED* to the title or edit the solution into the question. If an answer below solved the problem, you can upvote and mark it as accepted to let people know. If you discovered a different solution, you can write an answer below to share it with others; see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `char Name;` can only store a single character. Your code is allowing the user to type in multiple characters which are being stored into `Name` causing a memory error.

Change `char Name;` to something like `char Name[50]` so that you can store up-to 49 characters plus the `null` byte.

Also you should use `scanf_s()` properly to avoid the error if the buffer (char array) ends up being too small.

**Note, you should always check the return from `scanf_s()` so you know if the user entered valid data or not.**

This code works correctly in Visual Studio:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int Age;
    char Name[50];

    printf("Type your age: ");
    if(scanf_s("%d", &Age))
    {
        printf("Your age is %d\n", Age);

        printf("Type your Name: ");
        if (scanf_s("%s", Name, (unsigned)_countof(Name)))
        {
            printf("Your name is %s\n", Name);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Name:: Invalid Input\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Age:: Invalid Input\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to an array but still got "Exception thrown at 0x5B49D4EC (ucrtbased.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x001A0000. occurred"

Comment: Why `49` in `char Name[50]; ... scanf_s("%s", Name, 49);`?  Looks like an anti-pattern to [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2017).

Comment: Why `20` in `scanf_s("%d", &Age,20);`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you defined `Name` as a `char` - a single character - but you are trying to use it as a string (multiple characters).

To fix this you must either (a) define `Name` as an *array* of characters (which would be a string) - such as `char Name[100];` or (b) as a pointer (such as `char *Name;`) - which would require you to `malloc()` the string before use and `free()` it after use.

Strings can be tricky, as they are basically just arrays of `char`s, but that requires you to either know, or find a way to know, how many characters will be in the string.  You can read more about how to do that [here, in the documentation for scanf_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2017), which gives this example:

```
char c[4];
scanf_s("%4c", &c, (unsigned)_countof(c)); // not null terminated
```

Answer (score 0):

First off I would just use scanf(), not scanf_s().
  Furthermore you need to cast your Name variable as a string, which is an array of characters as I have defined it below. Using just char Name, means you have created a variable with room for just one character.

Hope this helps :)

```
 int main()
 {
     int Age;
     char Name[10];


     printf("Type your age: ");
     scanf("%d", &Age);
     printf("Your age is %d\n", Age);

     //Name

     printf("Type your Name: ");
     scanf("%s", &Name);
     printf("Your name is %s", Name);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your code and still got the error. "Exception thrown at 0x5B49D4EC (ucrtbased.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x001A0000. occurred"

Comment: Change `scanf("%s", &Name);` to `scanf("%s", Name);`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by going to...

Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols and select checkbox "Microsoft Symbol Servers", Visual Studio will download PDBs automatically.

Thanks for everyone's help :)

Comment: The code shown in your question most definitely is WRONG because you are scanning in a string (multiple chars ending with a NULL) and attempting to store the result into char which isn't a string and can only hold one character. I don't think you solution fixed the actual problem, unless you modified the code.